# How to load a model to use on ARFragment

Tags: android, kotlin, arcore

I'm trying to implement a AR app using sceneform and I want to load a model.glb to play:

```
placeObjectOnScene(arFragment!!, anchor, Uri.parse("model.glb"))

 @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    private fun placeObjectOnScene(fragment: ArFragment, anchor: Anchor, uri: Uri) {
        ModelRenderable.builder()
            .setSource(fragment.context, uri)
            .build()
            .thenAccept(Consumer { renderable: ModelRenderable? ->
                addModelToScene(
                    fragment, anchor, renderable!!
                )
            })
            .exceptionally { throwable: Throwable ->
                Toast.makeText(
                    fragment.context, "Error:" + throwable.message,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                )
                    .show()
                null
            }
    }
```

but when I run the app the model doesn't exist. I put the model on raw folder but the app can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing `model.glb` in the path `app/src/main/assets/` folder.

You can try it out using my forked repo: https://github.com/kelvinwatson/SceneView

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this Repository https://github.com/SceneView/sceneview-android it is mostly rewritten in Kotlin and a maintained version of SceneForm.
The README contains a section about glb files https://github.com/SceneView/sceneview-android#load-a-glbgltf-model
and two samples exists to load a glb file with and without AR.